# copying Pipfile and Pipfile.lock to a new project

Tags: python, pipenv

I have carefully created a Pipfile and Pipfile.lock file for Project A.  I'm now embarking on Project B which is similar but different than Project A, so I want to start with a copy of Pipfile and Pipfile.lock from Project A.  This will allow me to install new packages and make other modifications for Project B as needed.

So: Once I've copied Pipfile and Pipfile.lock over to my Project B directory, what command do I give to pipenv to create a new virtualenv and load up the specified modules?

*(I'm sure this is documented, but I can't decipher the terminology: do I "update" or "install" or "sync"?)*

Answer (score 1):

Throwing caution to the wind, I typed:

```
% cd Project_B
% cp ../Project_A/Pipfile ../Project_A/Pipfile.lock .
% pipenv sync
```

and pipenv created a new environment and loaded the required modules.  So that appears to be the solution.